# Can't insert tuple into a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to insert a date object in a list. But, on execution, the code raises a TypeError. Here's the code:

```py
values.append(datetime.date(tuple(checkIn)))
values.append(datetime.date(tuple(checkOut)))
```

For viewing pleasure, I provided only the lines that raises the error.

Here,

- `values` is a list
- `checkIn` and `checkOut` are lists. *eg-* `checkIn = [2020, 11, 28]`

This is the error message:

```
File "d:/coding/python/hms.py", line 195, in booking
    values.append(dt.date(tuple(checkIn)))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

**So, why can't I insert tuple into a list?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) `checkIn` and `checkOut` in order to pass the values as arguments:

```
import datetime as dt

values = []
checkIn = [2020, 11, 28]

values.append(dt.date(*checkIn))
print(values)
```

Out:

```
[datetime.date(2020, 11, 28)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
checkin=[yy,mm,dd]
values.append(datetime.date(checkin))
```

because the type error.